# How to create tomcatw.exe

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

What is the use tomcat6w.exe & tomcat6.exe ?

I am going to upgrade tomcat 6 to tomcat 8. I have downloaded tomcat 8 package from tomcat website but I did not find tomcat8w.exe & tomcat8.exe under bin folder.

It is available in my existing tomcat 6.0. How to create  tomcat8w.exe & tomcat8.exe ? I have already google for this but I did not understand how to create this, so please help me.

**Edit 1**

As per Jan Broos answer, I have downloaded 64 bit windows zip package, in this package tomcat8w.exe & tomcat8.exe are available under bin folder. Is it only for 64 bit windows ? why it's not available in default windows package ?

Answer (score 1):

They are both present in the Tomcat 8.5 package. You probably have the default zip downloaded. 
Download the 64-bit Windows zip on: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have downloaded 64 bit windows zip, now both .ext files are available under bin folder.

Comment: For  tomcat8w.exe & tomcat8.exe required to download 64 bit windows zip ? why it's not available in default zip package ?

Comment: It's the base distribution and does not contain specific windows wrappers. It hooks on windows services and the windows shortcuts [link](http://apache.cs.uu.nl/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.8/README.html)

Comment: depends on how you integrate it. But if you got win-32 there's a download for that too.

Comment: I want to use this in my existing application and it will work in both, windows 32 & 64 Bit